# How to stop django from skipping the login page for a user?

Tags: python, django, authentication

User not getting a chance to login. It just redirects to the 404 page:

Getting this 404 error:

Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/pk/invalid/

Using the URLconf defined in namekeepr.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order: 
The current URL, pk/invalid/, didn't match any of these.

This is my views.py file:

```
# Login Page
def login(request):
    username = request.POST.get('username', '')
    password = request.POST.get('password', '')
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None and user.is_active:
        # Correct password, and the user is marked "active"
        auth.login(request, user)
        # Redirect to a success page.
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/pk/loggedin/")
    else:
        # Show an error page
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/pk/invalid/")
```

Comment: The error message says that there was no pattern for `/pk/invalid/`. Can you show us the URLconf?

Comment: is namekeepr.urls included in your main urlConf?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `login_required()` decorator for your view functions.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def my_view(request):
    ...
```

It will by default redirect your users to LOGIN_URL defined in your settings.py.

**Example**

Here's a simple example of what happens from the user's perspective when you use the @login_required decorator:

1. The user types into their browser url `http://localhost:8000/my_view`
2. This url's view has an @login_required, and the user is redirect to the login page: `http://localhost:8000/login/?next=/my_view/`
3. After the user logins again, he/she is redirected automatically to `/my_view/`.

Comment: I want to have a login page as the 1st page, rather than having it be a redirect page for people who aren't already logged in. Also, I don't see the place to define by default LOGIN_URL in settings.py? I built a login.html page with a form for users to login and I want them to see that page when they go to the login view.

Comment: What do you mean by: "I want to have a login page as the 1st page"? Do  you mean you want to map the url http://localhost:8000/ to the login page? The login_required() decorator will redirect users to the original url once they login. As for the LOGIN_URL, you need to manually add that to settings.py